# How to get the Product Entity targeted in a Scheduled Update?

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise, catalog-staging

I am using 2.3.x Magento Enterprise.

I am able to get the schedules updates. And for brevity I'm using the Object Manager in my example as a proof of concept:

```
$om = ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria */
$searchCriteria = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface::class);
/** @var \Magento\Staging\Model\UpdateRepository $updateRepo */
$updateRepo = $om->get(\Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface::class);
/** @var \Magento\Staging\Model\ResourceModel\Update\Collection $updateList */
$updatesList = $updateRepo->getList($searchCriteria);
/** @var array $updateArray */
$updatesArray = $updatesList->getItems();

foreach ($updatesArray as $update) {
    /** @var \Magento\Staging\Model\Update $update */
}
```

I will further filter my results, (out of scope of my question) but I want to know how to get the `Product` entity that is related to my update (if it exists).

If I go into the admin to `Content > Content Staging Dashboard` I can see my target update and there is a product associated to that Update. It says

> This update includes 1 Objects

And underneath it, there is a link to the update where the data for my Product resides.

How can I get that `Product` through the `Magento\Staging\Model\Update` or something similar?

Comment: Found the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the current version using Magento's version manager. You can use the below function `getProductByScheduleId()` to get the product.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Folder;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class YourClass
{
    private VersionManager $versionManager;
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;
    private StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        VersionManager $versionManager,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->versionManager = $versionManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getProductByScheduleId(ProductInterface $product, int $scheduleId): ProductInterface
    {
        try {
            $this->versionManager->setCurrentVersionId($scheduleId);
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId(), true, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $product;
        }
        return $product;
    }

}
```